# How to select an item from a column using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
_path = 'B:\\Excel Files\\'


_file_list = glob.glob(_path + '*.xlsx')


concat_frame = []
for _file in _file_list:
    if '~$' in _file:
        print 'Temp file -> ', _file, ' ignored.'
    else:
    print 'Loading ' , _file 
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(_file)
        sheet_name_suffix = 'Sheet1'
        sheet_name = [s for s in xl.sheet_names if sheet_name_suffix in s][0]
        xl = xl.parse(sheet_name)
        keep_cols = ['CustID','DATE','Start_Time','CARD_NAME','Amount']
        xl = xl[keep_cols]
        concat_frame.append(xl)
master_frame = pd.concat(concat_frame, ignore_index=True)
analysis_groups = master_frame.groupby(by=['CustID','DATE','Start_Time'] & ['CARD_NAME']=='Visa')
analysis_sums = analysis_groups['Amount'].sum()
analysis_sums.reset_index().to_csv('B:\\Excel Files\\ Customerdata.csv', index=False)
```

I'm having trouble with this code but it works very with-- `analysis_groups = master_frame.groupby(by=['CustID','DATE','Start_Time','CARD_NAME']` but it's not working when I'm trying to filter the credit card types such as Visa, American Express,etc. please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would like the total of Visa Card only

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are trying to filter the rows in your dataset based on a specific `CARD_NAME`.

However groupby is a function which groups the data based only on the columns. From the groupby output, you can filter out by just selecting the specific card name you want.